# Running batch commands in AutoHotKey

Tags: batch, autohotkey

I am on AutoHotKey and I'd have to run an application via batch command. The command is quite articulated, it has the form of:

```
" -path of the application- " " -path of a text file-" /igs /bat
```

How can I do this, the command has to include the "'s since the path has spaces in some directories.

I tried:

```
Run(" -path of the application- " " -path of a text file-" /igs /bat )
```

but it gives me an error.

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Edit] your question and add the error message you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work :

```
Run(""" -path of the application- "" "" -path of a text file-"" /igs /bat" )
```

Also

```
Run('" -path of the application- " " -path of a text file-" /igs /bat')
```

Comment: The second one is running it properly, thaks a lot!!